# What is causing an extremely low memory fragmentation ratio?

Tags: memory, redis, memory-fragmentation

We are seeing some odd memory issues with our Redis 4.0.2 instances. The master instance has a ratio of 0.12, whereas the slaves have reasonable ratios that hover just above 1. When we restart the master instance, the memory fragmentation ratio goes back to 1 until we hit our peak load times and the ratio goes back down to less than 0.2. The OS (Ubuntu) is telling us that the redis instance is using 13GB of virtual memory and 1.6GB of RAM.  And once this happens, most of the data gets swapped out to disk and the performance grinds almost to a halt.

Our keys tend to last for a day or two before being purged. Most values are hashes and zsets with ~100 or so entries and each entry being less than 1kb or so.

We are not sure what is causing this. We have tried tweaking the OS [`overcommit_memory`](http://linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_overcommit_memory.html). We also tried the new `MEMORY PURGE` command, but that neither seem to help.  We are looking for other things to explore and suggestions to try. Any advice would be appreciated.

What is the likely cause of this and how can we bring the ratio back closer to 1?

Here is a dump of our memory info:

```
127.0.0.1:8000> info memory
# Memory
used_memory:12955019496
used_memory_human:12.07G
used_memory_rss:1676115968
used_memory_rss_human:1.56G
used_memory_peak:12955019496
used_memory_peak_human:12.07G
used_memory_peak_perc:100.00%
used_memory_overhead:19789422
used_memory_startup:765600
used_memory_dataset:12935230074
used_memory_dataset_perc:99.85%
total_system_memory:33611145216
total_system_memory_human:31.30G
used_memory_lua:945152
used_memory_lua_human:923.00K
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.13
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

And our memory stats:

```
127.0.0.1:8000> memory stats
 1) "peak.allocated"
 2) (integer) 12954706848
 3) "total.allocated"
 4) (integer) 12954623968
 5) "startup.allocated"
 6) (integer) 765600
 7) "replication.backlog"
 8) (integer) 1048576
 9) "clients.slaves"
10) (integer) 33716
11) "clients.normal"
12) (integer) 184494
13) "aof.buffer"
14) (integer) 0
15) "db.0"
16) 1) "overhead.hashtable.main"
    2) (integer) 17691184
    3) "overhead.hashtable.expires"
    4) (integer) 32440
17) "overhead.total"
18) (integer) 19756010
19) "keys.count"
20) (integer) 337422
21) "keys.bytes-per-key"
22) (integer) 38390
23) "dataset.bytes"
24) (integer) 12934867958
25) "dataset.percentage"
26) "99.853401184082031"
27) "peak.percentage"
28) "99.999359130859375"
29) "fragmentation"
30) "0.12932859361171722"
```

Comment: Also posted this question on the redis mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/17nbNJdQsd4